# Symfony2 with Ngix Bad gateway on hold f5

Tags: mysql, symfony, caching, nginx, vps

When I pressed f5 button in my webpage (5~ seconds kept, test purpose)
 my website displays

```
 "502 bad gateway"
```

I am using symfony 2.6 and mysql with PHP-fpm my VPS have 1GB RAM and 1 core CPU. the nginx log display:

```
2015/05/12 12:41:17 [error] 9541#0: *661 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

while connecting to upstream,

```
 client: 127.0.0.1, 
 server: localhost,
 request: "GET /app_dev.php/ HTTP/1.1", 
 upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:",
 host: "localhost"
```

The connection is lost after the test and return after 30 seconds~

**Question:** How can I configure Nginx to prevent that? I need that my website don't fall on many http request

Comment: You should increase value of `pm.max_children` in your php-fpm pool config

Comment: Thank you @OlimSaidov but it don't work, I just tried with different values and nothing change

Comment: Have you checked the [logs](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/)?

Comment: sure @ThomasPotaire but the only error is the same that above, the connection failed on many http request I had the same problem with apache and now with nginx